# How to design Angular Responsive Component with only CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angular, components

**I am** designing Angular component main layout `by default it is responsive`, which contains below components...

1. Navigation Component
2. Sidebar Component
3. Main Component
4. Container Component

**Problem is like below shown in Image**...

[image]

My structure of app.component.html is

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-main>
   <app-sidebar> </app-sidebar>
   <app-container> 
      <app-card> </app-card>
   </app-container>
   <app-container>  
      <app-card> </app-card>
   </app-container>
</app-main>
```

I am also using content projection here too. Each time when I am re-using `<app-container>` that would be considered as a new `row` inside the main component. Right now the problem I am facing is when I used `<app-container>` second time it displays outside of side-bar component just right below.

I want to display Each and Every `<app-container>` exactly right-Side of sidebar component. Each time new  component must display as a new row.

Note: At present, I am not using any CSS framework and I Need to have solved this problem without using any CSS framework, just using row CSS class only.

I am sharing project Link in here in this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5k9xl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

here I am doing How to design our own component in angular, Can anyone suggest best practices on how to do this as responsive too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to project all the content inside your sidenav and with a little bit of CSS you'll get what you want.

Take a look to [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmneqx). I've added the CSS you need.

Comment: Thank you for help, but one problem is by increasing `width of sidebar to 800px` content to right side is hiding. How to overcome to this porblem.